# How to implement rotating rectangle around circle in libGDX Box2D?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I want to implement rotating rectangle around cicrle in such way, that circle has no rotation, and rectangle has, and I could myself control rotation of this rectangle (I mean set its angular velocity). All object's are Box2D `Body` objects. Here is picture, what I want to have:

[image]

In my case rectangle touches circle, but I think it doesn't matter.

At first I tried to do it with two `Fictures` for same `Body`, but there was a problem with rotation: I couldn't have one ficture with rotation and another without.

I think, it should be somehow connected, but I don't know what exactly `Joint` I should use.

I tried to use `DistanceJoint`, but there was a problem, that I couldn't control Rectangle: when I even linear velocity of rectangle to 0 in `render()` method it continued to rotate.

Maybe are there another solutions?

P.S. It's important, that Cicrle should be `DynamicBody`, not `StaticBody`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `RevoluteJoint` to anchor the "*motor*" to a point in the world, and a `WeldJoint` to anchor the rotating box to the "*motor*".

In my example I've used two **static** bodies, one for the circle that shouldn't move, and one for a small box inside the circle that will serve as the anchor point in the world.

The dynamic `rotator` `Body` is attached to the `anchorBody` using the `RevoluteJoint` and then the `box` (which is also dynamic) is welded to the `rotator` (which serves as the engine) using a `WeldJoint'.

The result looks like this;
[image: Rotating boxes!]
Sorry about the artifacts, the gif capture seems to be broken.

Full source for the above looks like this;

```
package com.bornander.androidstudiosandbox;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Shape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.joints.RevoluteJointDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.joints.WeldJointDef;

public class MyAndroidStudioSandboxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    World world;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    Box2DDebugRenderer renderer;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(100, 100);
        camera.position.set(0,0,0);

        world = new World(Vector2.Zero, true);

        renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        Body visibleCircle = createCircle(5, 0, 0);
        visibleCircle.setType(BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody);

        Body anchorPoint = createBox(2, 2, 0, 0);
        anchorPoint.setType(BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody);

        Body rotator = createBox(4,4,0,0);
        rotator.setType(BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody);

        Body box = createBox(4,4,8,0);
        box.setType(BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody);


        RevoluteJointDef revoluteJointDef = new RevoluteJointDef();
        revoluteJointDef.initialize(anchorPoint, rotator, anchorPoint.getWorldCenter());
        revoluteJointDef.enableMotor = true;
        revoluteJointDef.motorSpeed = 20;
        revoluteJointDef.maxMotorTorque = 50;

        WeldJointDef weldJointDef = new WeldJointDef();
        weldJointDef.initialize(rotator, box, rotator.getWorldCenter());

        world.createJoint(revoluteJointDef);
        world.createJoint(weldJointDef);

    }

    private Body createBox(float w, float h, float x, float y) {
        BodyDef nodeBodyDefinition = new BodyDef();
        nodeBodyDefinition.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        nodeBodyDefinition.position.set(10, 10);

        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        float density = 1.0f;
        shape.setAsBox(w / 2.0f, h / 2.0f);

        Body body = world.createBody(nodeBodyDefinition);
        body.setUserData(this);
        body.setTransform(x, y, 0);
        final FixtureDef nodeFixtureDefinition = createFixtureDefinition(shape, density);

        body.createFixture(nodeFixtureDefinition);
        shape.dispose();

        return body;
    }

    private Body createCircle(float r, float x, float y) {
        BodyDef nodeBodyDefinition = new BodyDef();
        nodeBodyDefinition.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        nodeBodyDefinition.position.set(10, 10);

        CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
        float density = 1.0f;
        shape.setRadius(r);

        Body body = world.createBody(nodeBodyDefinition);
        body.setUserData(this);
        body.setTransform(x, y, 0);
        final FixtureDef nodeFixtureDefinition = createFixtureDefinition(shape, density);

        body.createFixture(nodeFixtureDefinition);
        shape.dispose();

        return body;
    }

    private static FixtureDef createFixtureDefinition(final Shape shape, final float density) {
        final FixtureDef nodeFixtureDefinition = new FixtureDef();
        nodeFixtureDefinition.shape = shape;
        nodeFixtureDefinition.friction = 1;
        nodeFixtureDefinition.density = density;
        nodeFixtureDefinition.restitution = 0.1f;
        return nodeFixtureDefinition;
    }



    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 4, 4);
        camera.update();

        renderer.render(world, camera.combined);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case I need Circle to be ```DynamicBody```. When I copied your code and changed ```Static``` to ```Dynamic```, everything has broken. How can I fix it? Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: In that case you need to set the collision filters and masks so that the circle does not collide with the anchor or the rotor. Or you could try setting the anchor and rotor to be sensors using `setSensor (true)`.

Comment: Ok, as I understand, RevoluteJoint is only for such joints where one of bodies doesn't change his place (we even set ```anchorPoint.getWorldCenter()``` as anchor point). So could you please explain your solution a little bit more in details?

Comment: @OneOne `RevoluteJoint` works on all bodies, not just when one is `static`  but if you make the thing that the box rotate around being `dynamic` then the centripetal force of the orbiting box will make the center `Body` wobble unless you have a very large difference in density. If you elaborate a bit more on how all the bodies in you example should behave I am certain a solution can be found that works well for you.